# How can I read particular Taxable Income and Tax on Income from file containing tax table?

Tags: java, readfile

How can I read the taxrates.txt file and get the information from that file and store it in a proper data structure?

taxrates.txt contains

```
Taxable Income     : Tax on Income

0 – $18,200        : 0

$18,201 – $37,000  : 19c for each $1 over $18,200

$37,001 – $90,000  : $3,572 plus 32.5c for each $1 over $37,000

$90,001 – $180,000 : $20,797 plus 37c for each $1 over $90,000

$180,001 and over  : $54,097 plus 45c for each $1 over $180,000
```

I have written code to read the file and get tax information from the file. But the problem is it can read the file and get data if data is in the proper format.
for example:

```
$0 – $18,200 : 0

$18,201 – $37,000 : 15

$37,001 – $90,000 : 18

$90,001 – $180,000 : 23
```

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("taxrates.txt"));
    while(sc.hasNext()){
         minRange=sc.nextDouble();
         sc.next()
         maxRange=sc.nextDouble();
         sc.next()
         taxRate=sc.nextDouble();
         printTaxInfo(minRange, maxRange, taxRate);
}
```

Someone please suggests me how to read the file which is not in the proper format.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "not in the proper format"? Like do you expect to read a file containing: `sdfg23sdvx45`?

Comment: If the taxrates.txt can contain lines your original program does not expect then you have two options: either return the file to your customer and explain its format is wrong or fix your program to parse all possible inputs. For the second case you could add another layer that transforms the given format to the expected one.

Comment: @Amongalen "not in the proper format" means table contains the value of column 'Tax on Income' as '0' or '19c for each $1 over $18,200' or '$3,572 plus 32.5c for each $1 over $37,000'. so it is not in proper format

Comment: Then your definition of "proper" is incorrect. "Proper" input to your program is something you expect to process, "improper" won't be processed, only some exception should be thrown. From what I understand you simply want to parse the file from the first quotation.